# LINQ OrderBy not ordering .. changing nothing .. why?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, sql-order-by, iqueryable

Any idea why the LINQ OrderBy is not working in following code, (have no errors but method does not sort ...)

First my own type

```
public class IQLinksView
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int catid { get; set; }
        public int? viewed {get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string desc {get;set;}
        public string url {get;set;}
        public string pic {get;set;}
        public string cat {get;set;}
    }
```

then query :

```
IQueryable<IQLinksView> newView = 
              from links in this.emContext.tbl_otherlinks
              select new IQLinksView { id = links.pklinkid, catid =
              links.tbl_catgeory.pkcategoryid, viewed = links.linkviewed, name = links.linkname, 
              desc = links.linkdesc, pic = links.linkpicture,   url = links.linkurl, cat =
              links.tbl_catgeory.categoryname };
```

Untill here all fine :-), but then

```
newView.OrderBy(x => x.viewed);
```

just changes nothing,... Page is loading results showing ... but no ordering ... sniff

i have Try with (creating a comparer object ... ):

```
newView.OrderBy(x => (Int32)x.viewed, new CompareIntegers());
```

same result, no ordering ...

I do have workarounds but just wondering what is missing ....

Any suggestions will be appreciated thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Don't throw away the return value. The `OrderBy` extension method is does *not* mutate the input. Try:

```
newView = newView.OrderBy(x => x.viewed);
```

There is no reason why that won't work, assuming the `viewed` value is correct. Also, make sure that `OrderBy` is after any operations (e.g. `Distinct`) which will ruin ordering.

Happy coding!

Comment: Super ! Works fine, did not think of the return, assumed mutation

Comment: My problem was I had it before a distinct.

Comment: I was ordering by a field that wasn't being displayed

Answer (score 1):

[No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries)

Consider use the  asnotracking() after orderby() if the result is a readonly result.

Example:

```
query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).AsNoTracking();
```