# C# Linq query in a Class doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, methods

I'm working on a ***school project*** and I have an issue.

I would like to sort my list by pokemon's speed. I've no problem to sort it in my main program (console)

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TabPokemon tab = new TabPokemon();
        PokemonSportif poke = new PokemonSportif("Pikachu", 110, 22, 1, 56);
        tab.Add(poke);
        PokemonSportif poke1 = new PokemonSportif("Salameche", 15, 2, 3, 56);
        tab.Add(poke1);
        PokemonSportif poke2 = new PokemonSportif("Bulbizar", 5, 8, 2, 56);
        tab.Add(poke2);
        PokemonSportif poke3 = new PokemonSportif("Mew", 10, 30, 1, 56);
        tab.Add(poke3);

        var sorted = from p in tab orderby p.vitesse() ascending select p;

        foreach(Pokemon p in sorted)
        {
            write(p.ToString() + " -- Vitesse: " + p.vitesse());
            sauterLigne();
        } 
        Console.Read();
    }
    static public void write(string chaine)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(chaine);
    }
    static public void sauterLigne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

But I would like to use my Linq query in a Class who's manage my List.

When I call my function, it doesn't work

My class:

```
class TabPokemon : List<Pokemon>
{
    List<Pokemon> PokeList;

    public TabPokemon()
    {
        PokeList = new List<Pokemon>();
    }

    public void orderBySpeedAscending()
    {
        var sorted = from p in PokeList orderby p.vitesse() ascending select p;
    }

}
```

And when I want to call it in my program with this instruction:

```
tab.orderBySpeedAscending();
```

my Array is not sort.

I don't know if you have understand but i would like to use void Method with linq query.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

```
class PokemonSportif : Pokemon
{
    int nbPattes;
    double taille, frqCardiaque;

    public int NbPattes
    {
        get
        {
            return nbPattes;
        }

        set
        {
            nbPattes = value;
        }
    }  

    public double Taille
    {
        get
        {
            return taille;
        }

        set
        {
            taille = value;
        }
    }

    public double FrqCardiaque
    {
        get
        {
            return frqCardiaque;
        }

        set
        {
            frqCardiaque = value;
        }
    }

    public PokemonSportif(string unNom, double unPoid, int unNbPattes, double uneTaille, double uneFrqCardiaque) : base(unNom, unPoid)
    {
        NbPattes = unNbPattes;
        Taille = uneTaille;
        FrqCardiaque = uneFrqCardiaque;
    }
    public override double vitesse()
    {
        return NbPattes * Taille * 3;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + " || Nombre de pattes: " + NbPattes + " || Taille: "+Taille + " || Frequence cardiaque: "+FrqCardiaque ;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are declaring a variable for the sorted listed with `var sorted = ...`, but your return type is `void`. you need to actually `return` the sorted list, not just assign it to a variable.

Comment: `PokeList = (from p in PokeList orderby p.vitesse() ascending select p).ToList();`

Comment: Could you post the constructor for your `PokemonSportif` class, as it's hard to see what you're passing in, actually is? At first glance, your `orderBySpeedAscending()` method is just creating a `sorted` `IEnumerable` and not doing anything else with it. Could you be more specific as to which part of your code is not working? You've got 2 OrderBy queries - which one is problematic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ OrderBy not ordering .. changing nothing .. why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743948/linq-orderby-not-ordering-changing-nothing-why)

Comment: done
The code is working, it's just that i want to create method (with linq query) in my class that manage my list

Comment: Why not create an extension method instead? The order of a list is usually only of interest in the presentation layer (at the point you want to display it), so having a custom List<> type with a sort is usually more trouble than its worth.

Answer (score 0):

Most linq queries do not modify the original list but instead return a new collection when the query is run.

```
public void orderBySpeedAscending()
{
    this.PokeList = (from p in PokeList orderby p.vitesse() ascending select p).ToList();
}
```

Doing the above will have the effect of replacing the referenced list in the PokeList variable.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work
The List is the same as the original :/

Comment: I see that you inherited List<Pokemon> into TabPokemon. If you're calling the Add method on TabPokemon then the pokemon never make it into your PokeList variable. Therefore sorting PokeList will never do anything as it never had any items in it to begin with.

If you want to sort the list in place while keeping a void sorting method, I'd advise you to use the Sort method and write a Comparer class instead of using linq. Probably this is what your teacher wants you to do anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In your function orderBySpeedAscending you assign the sorted result to a local variable named sorted, which then gets discarded when you exit the function.

You need to save the sorted result to a class member to preserve its value after the function exits.

Comment: Where can i save it ?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do.  The simplest thing is to  put the result back into your existing PokeList member.  See Igor's comment to your original question.  The ToList() is needed so that your result will be a list and so be the same data type as the PokeList member.

Comment: Also, you have two lists: one in the PokeList member and one inherited form the base class List<Pokemon>.  You are adding your pokemon to the list in the base class but then sorting the other list referenced by you class member PokeList.  You need to decid ewhether you are trying to encapsulate the list as a class member or inherit from it as a base class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void orderBySpeedAscending()
{
    var sorted = from p in PokeList orderby p.vitesse() ascending select p;
    this.PokeList = sorted.ToList();
}
```

This should set the list to the var you have sorted.

Comment: I have this message error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)