# MVC c# LINQ OrderByDescending isnt'working

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

Hello i have a problem using this query:

```
    @foreach (var formazioneanni in contesto.Formazione.OrderByDescending(o => o.FormazioneDataOrdinamento).Where(x => x.FormazioneEsperienzaLavorativa == true).Select(p => p.FormazioneAnnoOrdinamento).Distinct())
```

My wish is to get from table ALL years once in Descending order.
I get all years once by **.Select(p => p.FormazioneAnnoOrdinamento).Distinct()** and it works
But seems query don0t consider OrderBy. DESC or ASC simply igore.
If i place .OrderByDescending at the end of query it not works at all.

some one more expert then me can give me an int?

thx guys

Added missing information: i need to keep Distinct() method because i need to get value once.

Comment: Also the note at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743959/2957232). `Distinct` will ruin ordering apparently.